# I want to retrieve max value from two column - SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please find attached image for table structure

[image]

Comment: you could use MAX() ..

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING!?

Comment: Don't post image  .. post text  code and sample

Comment: @scaisEdge i want to get max value among from two column not from single column

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: anyway don't post image only  .. post code as text and a valid data sample as text  ..  otherwise  ,,  the S.O commuty must waste me for  coding you rewriting code form your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using UNION ALL for build a unique column result  and select the max from this

```
select max(col) 
from (
select col1 col
from  trans_punch
union all
select col2
from  trans_punch) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression to union the columns, then select the max.

```
;with cteUnionPunch(Emp_id, both_punch) AS
(
SELECT Emp_id, In_Punch FROM trans_punch 
UNION ALL
SELECT Emp_id, Out_Punch FROM trans_punch
)
SELECT Emp_id, max(both_punch) FROM cteUnionPunch GROUP BY Emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tp.Emp_id, max(tpp.Punchs)
from trans_punch as tp cross apply
     ( values (In_Punch), (Out_Punch) ) tpp(Punchs)
group by tp.Emp_id;
```